# Why the app shows black box when it in background

Tags: ios, background

In one my app, it shows top black box when it enter background.

Does any one see this before? How should I solve it? Many thanks if anyone can help.

First photo is the app in background.
Second one is the app in foreground.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a navigation bar and a status bar that both have a black background. Just change the style of them in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just add a new photo which the app runs in foreground.